# Interceptor me modifica headers en una petición que deseo no se modifique | Angular

Tags: angular, webservice, tokens

Tengo un interceptor el cual clona el `request` y modifica los `headers` mandandole a `Authorization` un `token` que recupero de localstorage cuando hago una petición a mi api:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    
    const token:  string = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let req = request;
    if(token){
      req = request.clone( {
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Token ${token}`
        }
      });
    } else{
      console.log("NOEXISTETOKEN")
    }
    
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Me funciona bien, el problema que tengo es que cuento con un servicio el cual consume otro servicio que no tiene nada que ver con mi api:

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_ESQUEMA);
}
```

Para consumir este servicio no necesito mandarle un `token` pero al hacer la petición el interceptor le manda el `token` y al no necesitar `token` y mandarle uno me devuelve un error `401 (Unauthorized)`

Como puedo hacer para que en una petición a una URL especifica no se molifiquen los `headers` en el interceptor para poder acceder a esta sin problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de esta forma:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const re = 'https://ws/schema?format=openapi-json';

    const token:  string = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let req = request;

    if (request.url !== re ) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
      });
    } 

    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder de esta manera y hacer la comparación:

```
if(request.url == 'https://abcd.azure.net/api/v1/getPendinList')
```